# Turning on Location (GPS) if it is turned off in Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I would like to get the location of a smartphone (service runs in background) if location is turned off. Is there a way to automatically activate the Location service if it is turned off? For locating the user the FusedLocationProvider is used.

I guess that there is no chance to get the location by WiFi, GPS or cell towers if the location sensor is turned off.

Comment: in Android O background service is not working. so no any method for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Even for Android Oreo you may turn on GPS if root available. 
This is actually universal for all recent Androids, at least Android Ice Cream and later.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't turn on the location automatically. The user has to give permission that's why it comes under `PROTECTION_DANGEROUS`.

Comment: And there is also no chance after giving permission?

Comment: Yes you can't automatically turn it on